# Looking up a value from a consistent string and outputting a series

Tags: microsoft-excel

**EXAMPLE PROBLEM**

I've currently got a problem where I want to create a look up for approximately 70 (with potential to increase) values from a consistent string, which is formatted in a similar fashion to this:

XXX-XX-XX-XX-XX-**X**-**0000**

Each string has predefined values that need to be populated that create a unique "number" for that object. I then want to search what kind of series that object falls into by using the **bold** values above

The series are presented like so

- Series 1 - A-1000 - General
- Series 2 - A-2000 - Specific item 1
- Series 3 - A-4000 - Specific item 2
- Series 4 - B-1000 - General
- Series 5 - B-2000 - Specific item 1
- Series 6 - B-3000 - Specific item 2

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

This pattern repeats for 70 or so series where it's LETTER-NUMBER and where the alphabetical component provides a category and then the number a subcategory.

I'm getting stuck on trying to figure out the logic to look up the values and return the series in a corresponding cell to the right of the number. Effectively creating an automated metadata assignment based on the numbers themselves.

**TESTED SOLUTIONS**

I've racked my brain for the last day or two, looking at various types of vlookups, index match, switch, find, search options across the board, but I think I'm a bit too close to it to find a solution or I don't have the full knowledge required to execute the task just yet.

Any assistance on this, which could be anything as simple as a link to a corresponding tutorial you think matches the problem statement or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks and kind regards,

E

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share some sample data along with the CODE you are supposed to looked up,,,, I think that U have described every thing but not the real task!!

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to:

1. extract the code from the end of the string, and
2. look up that code in a reference table

In the image below, I have the strings in `A2:A5` and the reference table in `A10:B13`. In cell `B2`, I've entered this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(RIGHT($A$2:$A$5,6),$A$10:$A$13,$B$10:$B$13,"Not found")
```

This single formula in `B2` has populated cells `B2:B5`, because the first parameter (inside the `RIGHT` function), is a cell range - i.e. an array. You should be able to adjust the ranges in this formula to suit your data.

[image]